# Firebase crashing in android 4.4.4

Tags: android, firebase, android-4.4-kitkat

App working fine in a lot of versions but crashing in 4.4.4

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
>   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzek(Unknown Source)

My app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0.12"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please include your source code in the question, not a link to the screenshot of your source code.

Comment: try set `minifyEnabled false`, that is most probably proguard problem

Comment: @DimaRostopira same error after set minifyEnable false

Comment: Are you confident that Multidex is enabled and working?  Do you see `logcat` messages with tag `Multidex` reporting successful initialization?  Also, it is not good practice to include `com.google.android.gms:play-services` as a dependency.  That adds all the Google APIs.  You'll see better build performance and possibly eliminate the problem by including only the APIs you need [(list here)](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. In my case,

1. My was configured for parse push notification. I got rid of that.
2. Updated Google Play Services and **Google Repository**.
3. Cleaned and Rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Application Tag in manifest file : 
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"